# Ограничить позиции джостика

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть метод:

```
public void OnDrag(PointerEventData data) {
    if (data.pointerId == lastId) {
        isFree = false;
        Vector3 position = bl_JoystickUtils.TouchPosition(m_Canvas, GetTouchID);
        if (Vector2.Distance(DeathArea, position) < radio) {
            StickRect.position = position;
        } else {
            StickRect.position = DeathArea + (position - DeathArea).normalized * radio;
        }
    }
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при перемещении джостика, значения наклонения и поворота были меньше, чтобы, когда выходим за пределы джостика значения не увеличивались.

Нужно как-бы ограничить, чтобы углы наклона и перемещения были меньше, чем сейчас.

Не могу врубиться как это сделать.

**UPD:**
Видать не то дал, джостик не причем, скорее всего дело тут:

```
private void TiltProcess() {
    hTilt.x = Mathf.Lerp(hTilt.x, hMove.x * 30f, Time.deltaTime);
    hTilt.y = Mathf.Lerp(hTilt.y, hMove.y * 20f, Time.deltaTime);
    rb.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(hTilt.y, rb.transform.localEulerAngles.y, -hTilt.x);
}
```

На сколько понял, это и отвечает за наклон или поворот, как его уменьшить, чтобы меньше поворот был и наклон?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в мов кортроллере, решилась через `Clamp`

```
hMove.x = Mathf.Clamp(hHor, -1, 1);
hMove.y = Mathf.Clamp(hVer, -1, 1);
```

Comment: Извините, в чём была проблема?

Comment: @0xdb, проблема в передвижении самого объекта была, так как движение ничем не ограничивалось, оно получалось с перебором величин, теперь движение в полном порядке.